# Where is the app.css in DurandalJS that enables modals?

Tags: javascript, css, durandal

I'm trying to get the modal to work in an app using the [DurandalJS](http://durandaljs.com/) (SPA) framework and can't get the modal to display correctly. Currently, when the modal opens, it displays without a blockout and fills the browser horizontally.

[image: incorrect modal]

("Feeds", the "New Feed" button, and the "Logout" link should be blocked out.)

I have read [the docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Modal-Dialog/) a few times and the only clue I can find is this note below the "The Default Modal Context" section:

> Note: The default modal context has some required css for positioning
>   which can be found in the app.css file. It assumes that the target
>   browser supports position: fixed. If your target browsers do not
>   support this, you should replace the default modal context with a
>   custom implementation.

It mentions an "app.css" file... I can't find it. I have searched DurandalJS's github repo and [the only app.css](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/skeletons/mimosa2/DurandalTemplate/assets/stylesheets/app.css?source=cc) file doesn't have anything that would really affect this modal (for good or bad). Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of `durandal.css` should get you started.
https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/Content/durandal.css

```
.modalBlockout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;

    pointer-events: auto;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
}

.modalHost {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s linear; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.messageBox {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like in this case the documentation didn't catch up with the changes made to Durandal. I send a pull request.